# Call to undefined function db2_connect() error is occured

Tags: php

My db2 database is on windows machine

my php application on Linux machines on xamp

when i start my app then error is occured 
error is :- Call to undefined function db2_connect()

Comment: Can you tell us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0):

[DB2](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ibm-db2.php) is an extension and must be installed separately before its functions are made available.

http://php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the ibm db2 extension:

http://php.net/manual/en/ibm-db2.installation.php